# Excel VBA - Run-time Error 13 - Type Mismatch

Tags: excel, vba, type-mismatch

The line that’s bombing out:

```
Size_1_Orig = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("Vo").Columns(Column_Name_1_Orig)) - 1
```

The objective of the code is to compare two similar spreadsheets with similar information, one from last year and the other from this year. I anticipate this being a yearly thing so I am trying to write it in a way to anticipate any issues I may have in the future with different file names, file types, and user input, but I digress.

The spreadsheet filters the columns that are relevant in hopes to reduce the size of the arrays. Once it’s filtered it take the two compare columns ("Mon From Bus Num" & "Con1 From Bus Num") and pulls the comments from the previous year and pastes those comments into the current years spreadsheet. **I am also not sure if the filtered/visible info into the array is working correctly, haven’t got to testing it**

It is bombing out where I am trying to size a dynamic array. I had this working on a simpler setup however when I converted the code over to work with the more complex spreadsheet it gave me the Type mismatch error.  I am in the debugging stage so there may be more errors in the code that I haven’t gotten to yet.

Any help would be appreciated. I am a novice when it comes to coding and would also take any pointers to make my code more efficient.

FULL CODE (so far)

```
Option Explicit

Global Username As String
Global ComboBox1 As String
Global ComboBox2 As String
Global WorkSh As Worksheet
Global FilterRow As Variant


Private Sub Test_Array()
'
' Test_Array Macro
'


    Dim Size_1_Orig As Integer
    Dim Size_2_Orig As Integer
    Dim Size_3_Orig As Integer
    Dim Size_1_Comp As Integer
    Dim Size_2_Comp As Integer
    Dim Size_3_Comp As Integer
    Dim i_Orig As Integer
    Dim i_Comp As Integer

    Dim Column_Name_1_Orig As String
    Dim Column_Name_2_Orig As String
    Dim Column_Name_3_Orig As String
    Dim Column_Name_1_Comp As String
    Dim Column_Name_2_Comp As String
    Dim Column_Name_3_Comp As String
    Dim Array_1_Orig() As String
    Dim Array_2_Orig() As String
    Dim Array_3_Orig() As String
    Dim Array_1_Comp() As String
    Dim Array_2_Comp() As String
    Dim Array_3_Comp() As String
    Dim path As String

    Column_Name_1_Orig = "Mon From Bus Num"
    Column_Name_2_Orig = "Con1 From Bus Num"
    Column_Name_3_Orig = "TP Comments"

    Column_Name_1_Comp = "Mon From Bus Num"
    Column_Name_2_Comp = "Con1 From Bus Num"
    Column_Name_3_Comp = "TP Comments"


    'Get the window username so that the program can be installed on any users desktop
    Username = Environ$("username")

''''KEEP''''
''''KEEP''''    ComboBox1 = Compare.ComboBox1.Value
''''KEEP''''    ComboBox2 = Compare.ComboBox2.Value
''''KEEP''''
''''KEEP''''   'close Userform
''''KEEP''''   Unload Compare_ITP_P3_Files

'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
''''' FOR TESTING PURPOSES TO BYPASS THE USERFORM '''''
    ComboBox1 = "2019.xlsx"
    ComboBox2 = "2020.xlsx"
''''' FOR TESTING PURPOSES TO BYPASS THE USERFORM '''''
'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


'----Open Wordbook-----

    Call Open_Workbook_Orig
    Sheets("Vo").Select
    Range("A1").Select

'------------------------------ Find Original spreadsheet values & place them in an array ----------------------------------
    'Arrays start counting at 0

    Size_1_Orig = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("Vo").Columns(Column_Name_1_Orig)) - 1
    Size_2_Orig = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("Vo").Columns(Column_Name_2_Orig)) - 1
    Size_3_Orig = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("Vo").Columns(Column_Name_3_Orig)) - 1

    ReDim Array_1_Orig(Size_1_Orig)
    ReDim Array_2_Orig(Size_2_Orig)
    ReDim Array_3_Orig(Size_3_Orig)

    For i_Orig = 0 To Size_1_Orig
        Array_1_Orig(i_Orig) = Cells(i_Orig + 1, Column_Name_1_Orig).Value

'        Debug.Print Array_1_Orig(i_Orig)

    Next i_Orig

    For i_Orig = 0 To Size_2_Orig
        Array_2_Orig(i_Orig) = Cells(i_Orig + 1, Column_Name_2_Orig).Value

'        Debug.Print Array_2_Orig(i_Orig)

    Next i_Orig

    For i_Orig = 0 To Size_3_Orig
        Array_3_Orig(i_Orig) = Cells(i_Orig + 1, Column_Name_3_Orig).Value

'        Debug.Print Array_3_Orig(i_Orig)

    Next i_Orig

'------------------------------ Find Compare spreadsheet values & place them in an array ----------------------------------

    Call Open_Workbook_Comp
    Sheets("Vo").Select
    Range("A1").Select

    Size_1_Comp = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("Vo").Columns(Column_Name_1_Comp)) - 1
    Size_2_Comp = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("Vo").Columns(Column_Name_2_Comp)) - 1
    Size_3_Comp = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("Vo").Columns(Column_Name_3_Comp)) - 1

    ReDim Array_1_Comp(Size_1_Comp)
    ReDim Array_2_Comp(Size_2_Comp)
    ReDim Array_3_Comp(Size_3_Comp)

    For i_Comp = 0 To Size_1_Comp
        Array_1_Comp(i_Comp) = Cells(i_Comp + 1, Column_Name_1_Comp).Value

'        Debug.Print Array_1_Comp(i_Comp)

    Next i_Comp

    For i_Comp = 0 To Size_2_Comp
        Array_2_Comp(i_Comp) = Cells(i_Comp + 1, Column_Name_2_Comp).Value

'        Debug.Print Array_2_Comp(i_Comp)

    Next i_Comp

    For i_Comp = 0 To Size_3_Comp
        Array_3_Comp(i_Comp) = Cells(i_Comp + 1, Column_Name_3_Comp).Value

'        Debug.Print Array_3_Comp(i_Comp)

    Next i_Comp

'------------------------------ Compare both arrays ----------------------------------

    Sheets("Vo").Select
    Range("A2").Select


    For i_Orig = 0 To Size_1_Comp

        If Array_1_Orig(i_Orig) = Array_1_Comp(i_Orig) And Array_2_Orig(i_Orig) = Array_2_Comp(i_Orig) Then

            Cells(i_Orig + 1, Column_Name_3_Comp).Value = Array_3_Orig(i_Orig)

        End If

        On Error Resume Next

    Next i_Orig
'

End Sub

Private Sub Open_Workbook_Orig()

    Dim strBookName As String
    Dim wb As String
    Dim path As String

    path = "C:\Users\" & Username & "\Desktop\P3 output\"
    wb = ComboBox1


    strBookName = ComboBox1
    If BookOpen(strBookName) Then
        Application.WindowState = xlNormal
        Windows(ComboBox1).Activate
        Application.WindowState = xlMaximized

        Set WorkSh = Sheets("Vo")
        WorkSh.Activate

''''
''''
'''' ----------**************** The line below might bomb out if all filters are already open, haven't tested  ****************----------
''''
''''

        ActiveSheet.ShowAllData ' --------- opens all the filters
        FilterRow = Rows("1:1").Find(What:="Run Type", lookat:=xlWhole).Column   ' --------- Filter Columns
        WorkSh.UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=FilterRow, Criteria1:="P3" ' --------- Filter Columns
        FilterRow = Rows("1:1").Find(What:="TP Comments", lookat:=xlWhole).Column ' --------- Filter Columns
        WorkSh.UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=FilterRow, Criteria1:="<>" ' --------- Filter Columns
    Else
        Workbooks.Open path & wb
        Application.WindowState = xlMaximized
        Sheets("Vo").Select
        ActiveSheet.ShowAllData ' --------- opens all the filters
        FilterRow = Rows("1:1").Find(What:="Run Type", lookat:=xlWhole).Column   ' --------- Filter Columns
        WorkSh.UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=FilterRow, Criteria1:="P3" ' --------- Filter Columns
        FilterRow = Rows("1:1").Find(What:="TP Comments", lookat:=xlWhole).Column ' --------- Filter Columns
        WorkSh.UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=FilterRow, Criteria1:="<>" ' --------- Filter Columns

    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Open_Workbook_Comp()

    Dim strBookName As String
    Dim wb As String
    Dim path As String

    path = "C:\Users\" & Username & "\Desktop\P3\"
    wb = ComboBox2


    strBookName = ComboBox2
    If BookOpen(strBookName) Then
        Application.WindowState = xlNormal
        Windows(ComboBox2).Activate
        Application.WindowState = xlMaximized
        Sheets("Vo").Select
        ActiveSheet.ShowAllData ' --------- opens all the filters
        FilterRow = Rows("1:1").Find(What:="Run Type", lookat:=xlWhole).Column   ' --------- Filter Columns
        WorkSh.UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=FilterRow, Criteria1:="P3"
        FilterRow = Rows("1:1").Find(What:="TP Comments", lookat:=xlWhole).Column
        WorkSh.UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=FilterRow, Criteria1:="<>"
    Else
        Workbooks.Open path & wb
        Application.WindowState = xlMaximized
        Sheets("Vo").Select
        ActiveSheet.ShowAllData ' --------- opens all the filters
        FilterRow = Rows("1:1").Find(What:="Run Type", lookat:=xlWhole).Column   ' --------- Filter Columns
        WorkSh.UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=FilterRow, Criteria1:="P3"  ' --------- Filter Columns
        FilterRow = Rows("1:1").Find(What:="TP Comments", lookat:=xlWhole).Column  ' --------- Filter Columns
        WorkSh.UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=FilterRow, Criteria1:="<>"  ' --------- Filter Columns

    End If
End Sub

Function BookOpen(strBookName As String) As Boolean
    Dim oBk As Workbook
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oBk = Workbooks(strBookName)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If oBk Is Nothing Then
        BookOpen = False
    Else
        BookOpen = True
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Is that column a named range? Use `Range` instead of `Columns`.

Comment: Also, don't use `Integer`, [use `Long`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26409117/why-use-integer-instead-of-long).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you BigBen, you got me on the right track. I didn't realize what you mentioned about columns.

I was able to achieve what I needed by using the following

```
    For Each Cell In Range("A1:CC1")
        If Cell.Value = Column_Name_1_Orig Then
            Cell.Select
            Size_1_Orig = Cells(Rows.Count, ActiveCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row - 1
            Size_1_Orig_Count = Size_1_Orig_Count + 1
            Exit For
        End If
        Size_1_Orig_Count = Size_1_Orig_Count + 1
    Next
```

Thank you again!